# How do I get thumbnail of a video in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, video-thumbnails

I want some help in creating thumbnail of a video being recorded from my android phone and I got this code from this [Link](https://acadgild.com/blog/android-video-capture-example-using-camera), and I modified this part of the code to generate the thumbnail but somehow the thumbnail is not being generated, so any help will be appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
        videoFileUri = data.getData();
        if (videoFileUri != null) {
           Bitmap image= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileUri.toString(),MODE_APPEND);

 ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        }

        playVideoButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're creating the thumbnail Bitmap (I assume) and then do nothing with it. Is this really all the relevant code?

Comment: i have to set that bitmap inside an imageview, now i have edited my answer pls have a look at it

Comment: @VipulSingh  please try to load bitmap using Picasso or Glide i have check its working all the time.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50941805/5077421) _italic_ **bold**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `glide.` its automatically set thumb image of video.

**Glide is also able to display the thumbnail of videos, as long as they're stored on the phone.** Let's assume you get the file path by letting the user select a video: Based on this document https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/example_video.mp4";

Glide  
    .with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)))
    .into(imageViewGifAsBitmap);
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, i just had to do some modification in my code to generate the path of the captured video then it was all done , thanks man

Comment: It's my glad to help you :) Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: @VipulSingh Can you please upvote my answer? if you can.

Comment: Yes of course, i want this answer to be above in the ranks so more and more people should get benefited

Comment: But im using fresco and its not set thumb automaticaly, so what should I do, i already upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks mate I was trying to get through ThumbnailUtils but it was taking time but this works like a charm.

Comment: Perfect answer, Get rid of OOM crash from exoplayer in recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete tested working solution:

Try it.

```
    if (videoFileUri != null) {

                        Bitmap bitmapThumb = null;
                        try {
                            bitmapThumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileUri.toString(),
                                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);// MINI_KIND, size: 512 x 384 thumbnail | MICRO_KIND, size: 96 x 96 thumbnail

                            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
//                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapThumb);

                            Uri uri = getImageUri(context, bitmapThumb);

                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(uri)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_imagedefault)
                                    .error(R.drawable.ic_imagedefault)
                                    .resize(350, 200)//as per need.
                                    .centerCrop()
                                    .into(imageView);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            bitmapThumb = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Here is the static method for **getImageUri** :

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Uri.parse("");
    }

}
```

Comment: i did it all but it does not seem to be working here...i don't know why

Comment: @VipulSingh what did you use in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

This works fine for me.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils

Comment: This way is deprecated.

Answer (score -4):

```
Uri uri = getImageUri(context, bitmapThumb);
Glide.with(getContext()).
load(uri).
thumbnail(0.1f).
into(imageView);
```