# How to get video thumbnail as GIF from video URL?

Tags: android, kotlin, animated-gif, video-thumbnails, mediametadataretriever

I want to show video thumbnail as GIF from video URL like [TikTok - including musical.ly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhiliaoapp.musically) app.

[See below video for getting more details](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aFRq0FoPITEyZJr6p8AAjDdHuXULcgVc)

I have used this to get first 10-15 video frames to generate GIF. but it's not working.

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

  mediaMetadataRetriever .setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
  Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1000); //unit in microsecond
  capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bmFrame);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943575/how-to-create-thumbnail-of-video-url-form-server/44943830#44943830

Comment: Check this answer and link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942061/6238866

Comment: @NiteshRathod
Tried that but getting below error.

 java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:102)

Comment: @MayurPatel
It is for normal video thumb. but i want thumb as GIF format. like this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aFRq0FoPITEyZJr6p8AAjDdHuXULcgVc

Comment: Just use this code like .          String bitmapPath = SaveImage(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND));

Comment: String SaveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + FileUtils.mediaPath);
        bitmap = "MY_IMAGE" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, bitmap);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete(){
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        bitmap = String.valueOf(file);
        return bitmap;
    }

Comment: @AkashPatel do you means you need to GIF image for video view?

Comment: @MayurPatel 
I want to show GIF as video thumbnail until video is ready to play. and I will show it on ImageView.

Comment: @AkashPatel did you got any solution for this thread? I also need to implement this feature. if you know please update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RaoArsalan Not yet, I'm generating GIF from mobile and storing it on server.